# Error NPM run dev (windows 7)

Tags: laravel, windows, cmd

Después de instalar laravel en su version 8.28.1 quiero ejecutar:

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

Y me sale el error:

> El símbolo (token) '&&' no es un separador de instrucciones válido en esta versión.
> En línea: 1 Carácter: 15
>
> - npm install && <<<<  npm run dev
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (&&:String) [],
>   ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

El SO que tengo es Windows 7 ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

pongan los comandos por separado

```
npm i

npm run watch
```